# Setting \textwidth seems to break textblock* command from textpos package?

Tags: positioning, margins, textpos

I would like to position text absolutely using the `textblock*` command from the `textpos` package. Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
% \renewcommand{\textwidth}{17cm} % (*)
\begin{document}
  \begin{textblock*}{3cm}(1cm,0.98\paperheight)
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  \end{textblock*}
\end{document}
```

This breaks as soon as I redefine the `textwidth` as done by the line marked `(*)` above. Why is this and, more importantly, how can I fix this? ("It breaks" here means I get *"! Missing number, treated as zero. ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)."* in the line with the text (placeholder "X...X" above).)

Bonus question: How can I specify something like `\paperheight - 1cm`?

Comment: \textwidth is a length not a macro: `\setlength\textwidth{17cm}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `\setlength` instead of `\renewcommand` and also `\dimexpr\paperheight-1cm\relax` for the second question :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\textwidth}{17cm} % (*)
\begin{document}
  \begin{textblock*}{3cm}(1cm,\dimexpr\paperheight-1cm\relax)
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  \end{textblock*}
\end{document}
```

[image]